# How do I return the value of the key pressed in React

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react - trying to build a fairly simple app. What I would like to do is just get and `console.log` the value of the key pressed by the user (eg. if user presses `k` then `k` appears in `console.log`).

This is what I have so far:

```
import "./TextArea.css";

const TextArea = () => {
  const registerKeyPresses = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  return (
    <form className="textinputframe">
      <div className="textinputframe">
        <textarea
          className="textinput"
          type="text"
          onKeyDown={registerKeyPresses}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default TextArea;
```

And this is what it returns:

```
SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onKeyDown', _targetInst: null, type: 'keydown', nativeEvent: KeyboardEvent, target: textarea.textinput, …}
altKey: false
bubbles: true
cancelable: true
charCode: 0
code: "MetaLeft"
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 3
getModifierState: ƒ modifierStateGetter(keyArg)
isDefaultPrevented: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()
isPropagationStopped: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()
isTrusted: true
key: "Meta"
keyCode: 91
locale: undefined
location: 1
metaKey: true
nativeEvent: KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: 'Meta', code: 'MetaLeft', location: 1, ctrlKey: false, …}
repeat: false
shiftKey: false
target: textarea.textinput
timeStamp: 9066952.4
type: "keydown"
view: Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
which: 91
_reactName: "onKeyDown"
_targetInst: null
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Use `console.log(e.target.value)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [`keydown` event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event). From there you'll see that

1. `keydown` events are all also [`KeyboadEvent`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)
   and
2. All `KeyboardEvent`s have a [`.code` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) that corresponds to the physical key pressed on the keyboard that produced the event (e.g. `MetaLeft` in your example)

Now you could console log the physical key if that's useful for you, or — if you're looking for only the *output* of the keypress, there's a [`.key` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) in `KeyboardEvent`s you can use instead.

The difference in `.code` and `.key` in a nutshell is that if you press e.g. the 'k' key on your keyboard, `.code` will equal `"KeyK"` and `.key` will equal `"k"`.

*If you instead want the value of the textarea* you can use [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) (since `keydown` is a `KeyboardEvent` which is an `Event`), which corresponds to the textfield element. The element will have [a `.value` prop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) that will equal the value of the textfield.

Comment: Thank you this was an extremely lucid answer - very helpful. Apologies for the simple question.